# Create sub-components in angular?

Tags: json, angular, parsing

I would like to know what are the possibilities to create little components in angular, which can be shown up when the data will be parsed. Let's say that we have a file (for example in json):

```
[{
  "name":"John",
  "surname:"Doe",
  "references":[{
     "surname": "One"},{
     "surname": "Two"}]
}]
```

So, I would like to create a component which targets the "surname" node, despite its depth into the tree.
Can you suggest a way to implement it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you be more specific on the purpose of this component? Should it display every surname inside the given Array or else? Also, you should show what you tried already to implement this component.

Comment: Thanks Federico,
What I am trying to achieve is to create -let's say- a `surname` component, that should target the relevant json node, despite of the depth. 
So let's say that inside the `app-component` the `surname-component` should display that node with the same template. 
Tell me please if it isn't too clear.

Comment: So if you have a JSON with 3 surnames (wherever they are and doesn't matter how deep they are), you should display 3 surname components, right?

Comment: Or is just one surname components which get as Input the whole JSON and search for the surnames inside it?

Comment: Wow this is a wonderful question.
For now I would like to solve it as in the first way you described (3 surnames wherever they are), but I admit that also the second could be a very interesting way.
Thanks a lot for your efforts, could you please elaborate how to get these 3 surname components?

Comment: The solution I found is more complex, but I think it's also more useful, if you wish to reuse this logic.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I created a component which works with any key you need (not only surname).

**key.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  ContentChild,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  TemplateRef
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "key-component",
  templateUrl: "./key.component.html"
})
export class KeyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() json: Object;
  @Input() key: string;
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
  template: TemplateRef<any>;
  items: Array<any>;

  ngOnChanges() {
    // If the key or the JSON change, revaluate items
    if (this.key && this.json)
      this.items = this.getElementsWithSelectedKey(
        this.objectDeepKeys(this.json)
      );
  }

  // Get all the values that has the key given by Input
  getElementsWithSelectedKey(keys: Array<String>) {
    return keys
      .filter((x: String) => x.endsWith(`.${this.key}`) || x === this.key)
      .map(x => {
        let currValue = this.json;
        for (let str of x.split(".")) {
          currValue = currValue[str];
        }
        return currValue;
      });
  }

  // Finds all the keys for every sub-objects in depth
  objectDeepKeys(obj: Object) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
      .filter(key => obj[key] instanceof Object)
      .map(key => this.objectDeepKeys(obj[key]).map(k => `${key}.${k}`))
      .reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y), Object.keys(obj));
  }
}
```

**key.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { $implicit: items }"></ng-container>
```

This component gets a json to check (in your case the whole array) and a key to seek (in your case "surname").
It checks for each key inside the json and save into the property `items` an array with all the values it has found, with the given key.

Now you just have to choose your template (you have to write an `ng-template` between the `key.component`'s tags) and get the context (`let-items` creates a variable `items` with the elements from the property `items` into `key.component`) to change your view as you wish.

Example:
**app.component.html**

```
<key-component [json]="myJSON" key="surname">
    <ng-template let-items>
        <surname-component *ngFor="let item of items" [surname]="item">
        </surname-component>
    </ng-template>
</key-component>
```

You can see the whole code with a couple of JSON to test on this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hvwkpg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I will study it. Thanks a lot, it is very useful.

Comment: Dear Federico, thank you so much for your efforts: this code is very useful to me. 
Just to ask if I am understanding it correctly: it displays the -let's say- surname key and extract them.
Maybe I wasn't clear enough, while I was searching for a way to create a schema which automatically calls the surname component when the json is parsed. So for example, it will attach a name component on name node, a surname on surname, and so on, without doing it programmatically. 
If it is not clear tell me please, and thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok now I understand, this is a more complex problem to solve, cause you need to create components dynamically. In my solution, as you can see, I solve the problem "If there is a property named as key create a precise set of elements that you find inside the ng-template". This kind of problem is "easy" cause you know before running you're code what components you're going to use (in this case just surname). To solve your problem, you don't know how many and what kind of components you need cause that depends on your JSON. In these situations the component factory comes in handy.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader check this link. Anyway I'll try to show you an example on Stackblitz in the next few days.

Comment: Grazie, Federico. thank you so much. I definitely will study it a lot because it's far more difficult than I expected :) 
Thank you for having addressed me in the right direction !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by ' little components in angular' but if you want to map responses from json file you can use class:

```
export class People {
    name: string,
    surname: string,
    references: othersurname[]
}

export class othersurname {
    surname: string
}
```